# Jest arrays toEqual() not working properly with space strings

Tags: javascript, jestjs

When using toEqual(), toContain() or toContainEqual() on two arrays, the Jest assertion fails on two arrays containing a space string

code:

```
    const actual = await viewIdentityPage.getEntitlementsByRowColumn(1, -1);
    const expected =["racfClassName","JESSPOOL"," ","zOS","LY700B"];
    console.log(actual);
    console.log(expected);
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
```

console.log on actual and expected arrays:

[image]

error:

[image]

as seen in the console error, Jest suggests that I have a space string in my expected that isn't in the actual, and that the actual has a space string that is not present in the expected.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Can you share a [mcve]? You probably have some sort of non-ASCII space character there.

Answer (score 0):

The "space" from the actual response was actually a &nbsp. Console logs couldn't show it, but testing if the third array object == "\xa0" yielded true